# how to set set pagination in category.php page in WordPress..?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I want add pagination on category page then i add pagination showing page not found error how i can add pagination and where is I am wrong my code is this.

```
    <?php 

        wp_reset_query(); 
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
        $args = array('cat_name'=>'cars', 'posts_per_page' => 8,'orderby' => 'ASC','paged'=>$paged );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 

        <div class="jokes">
            <div class="abcd">
                <?php echo the_title();?>
            </div>

        <?php echo the_content(); ?> <br><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Leave a comment </a>
        <?php  echo do_shortcode('[wp_social_sharing]');  ?></div>
        <?php 
            endwhile; 
            wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $loop) ); 
            wp_reset_query();           
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is works fine for me

```
        <?php if ($loop->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
        <?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="arrow">&larr;</span> Older' ) ); ?>
        <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer <span class="arrow">&rarr;</span>' ) ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78718/how-to-get-my-loop-to-paginate

Comment: thank you for replay but this code is not working nothing get any result not showing pagination

Comment: please set post per page in admin panel